# Social Engine Get Logged In User from custom php page

Tags: zend-framework, socialengine

I have seen and used the methods of obtaining the logged in user is for social engine pages.  I am wondering how can I pull the logged in user into a custom php page created outside the social engine network. I link to a few custom pages from my social engine site but want to tie into the existing Zend Frameworks session and grab those session variables.  Is this possible and how is it done?

Thanks

Shaun Roos

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should keep within SocialEngine and the Zend framework in order to access the session state etc. However you could possibly create an api or make a call to the database and select the sessions data for the user that is currently using the site. I'd store this externally in a cookie (perhaps the user's id encrypted in a format that allows you to decrypt it) then use the user_id in the cookie to select that data from the db.

Another way if you are on the same server and the same php instance is to use $_SESSION variables and store the required data in there and access it externally from your social engine installation.